# How many Deep Space stations are there?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, star-trek-ds9, space-station

We know of the station Deep Space Nine of course, and we have heard of Deep Space Five, I believe.  How many "Deep Space" stations are there?  Which is the closest to Sector 001 and which is the farthest?

Please provide a source.

Comment: This is three possibly two questions.

Comment: It’s simple: there’s Deep Space, Deep Space 3, Deep Space X 10.10.1, Deep Space ’95, Deep Space ME, Deep Space Creative Cloud, Deep Space 3.11, Deep Space XP, Deep Space 360, Deep Space 6S Plus, and finally, Deep Space One.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## It depends

### In Canon

Memory Alpha lists the following **7** Deep Space Stations:

- [Deep Space Station K-7](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Deep_Space_Station_K-7) (TOS: "The Trouble with Tribbles"; DS9: "Trials and Tribble-ations")
- [Tau Ceti Deep Space Station](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Tau_Ceti_Deep_Space_Station)
- [Deep Space 3](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Deep_Space_3) (TNG: "Interface")
- [Deep Space 4](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Deep_Space_4) (TNG: "The Chase", VOY: "The Gift")
- [Deep Space 5](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Deep_Space_5) (TNG: 'Parallels', *Star Trek: First Contact*)
- [Deep Space 7](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Deep_Space_7) (VOY: "In the Flesh")
- [Deep Space 9](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Deep_Space_9) (DS9)

### Out of Canon

Memory Beta lists the following **25** Starfleet/Federation stations entitled 'Deep Space X':

- [1](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/Deep_Space_1)
- [2](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/Deep_Space_2)
- [3](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/Deep_Space_2)
- [4](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/Deep_Space_4)
- [5](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Deep_Space_5)
- [6](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/Deep_Space_6)
- [7](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/Deep_Space_7)
- [8](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/Deep_Space_8)
- [9 (I)](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/Deep_Space_9)
- [9 (II)](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/Deep_Space_9_%28II%29)
- [10](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/Deep_Space_10)
- [E-5](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/Deep_Space_Station_E-5)
- [G-6](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/Deep_Space_Station_E-5)
- [K-2](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/Deep_Space_Station_K-2)
- [K-5](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/Deep_Space_Station_K-5http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/Deep_Space_Station_K-5)
- [K-7](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/Deep_Space_Station_K-7)
- [K-8](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/Deep_Space_Station_K-8)
- [K-10](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/Deep_Space_Station_K-10)
- [K-11](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/Starbase_K-11)
- [K-12](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/Deep_Space_Station_K-12)
- KR-1
- [KR-3](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/Space_Station_KR-3)
- [M-20](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/Deep_Space_Station_M-20)
- [M-33](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/Deep_Space_Station_M-33)
- [R-5](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/Deep_Space_Station_R-5)
- [Portal 1](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/Portal_1)

I think the closest Deep Space station to Sector 001 was probably the Tau Ceti space station, with the Tau Ceti station being just 20 light years away ([Source](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Tau_Ceti#Appendices)).

Based on looking through the below map, the farthest Deep Space station from Sector 001 is probably K7, right on the border of the Klingon Empire.

Please appreciate that not all of the space stations could be compared, simply because several of them are merely mentioned in passing and no specific location is provided.

[image]

Comment: As of Picard S3E1, you can add Deep Space 11 to that list, which one can infer from the dialogue is likely close to where DS4 was, perhaps as a replacement after decommissioning (Scene with capt of Titan, Picard make a ruse about going to DS4, the captain says something to the effect of DS4 being decommissioned a year prior and 7of9 interjects "What the admiral means is DS11" or something to that effect.